# Events objects not rendering or scope not broadcasting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I am trying to render my events using ionic-calendar ,through the `$scope.loadEvents` method. However, it is not rendering on my calendar.

Link to plugin used:
https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic-Calendar

I am not sure if it is due to my events not returning properly in the `getEvent()` function or due to inserting `$scope.$broadcast('eventSourceChanged',$scope.eventSource);` at the wrong place ( as instructed by the plugin's documentation.

This is the code in my controller file:

```
    $scope.loadEvents = function () {
        $scope.calendar.eventSource = getEvents();
        $scope.$broadcast('eventSourceChanged',$scope.eventSource);

    };

    function getEvents(object){

      var deferred = $q.defer();

        TimeSlotsModel.all()
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.data = result.data.data;

                var events = [];

                 angular.forEach(vm.data, function(value,key) {

                    var eventName = value.name;
                    var startDate = new Date(value.startDate);
                    var endDate = new Date(value.endDate);

                    var selectedStartingTime =new Date(value.startTime * 1000 );
                    var selectedEndingTime = new Date(value.endTime * 1000);

                    //timing is not right, needs fixing
                    startTime = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(),selectedStartingTime.getHours(), selectedStartingTime.getUTCMinutes());
                    endTime = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate(),selectedEndingTime.getUTCHours(), selectedEndingTime.getUTCMinutes());                     
                    // console.log(startTime);
                    events.push({
                        title: 'Event -' + eventName,
                        startTime: startTime,
                        endTime: endTime,
                        allDay: false

                    });
            // console.log(eventName);
            console.log(events);
            // console.log(value);
            // console.log(key);
            // console.log(value);

             //value is the object!!
            })

            deferred.resolve(events);



            })
            return deferred.promise;

         }
```

Comment: Please provide minimal code which can reproduce your issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @beaver thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue by directly assigning the events array to $scope.calendar.eventSource in the following:

```
    function getEvents(object){

    TimeSlotsModel.all()
        .then(function (result) {
            vm.data = result.data.data;

            var events = [];

             angular.forEach(vm.data, function(value,key) {

                var eventName = value.name;
                var startDate = new Date(value.startDate);
                var endDate = new Date(value.endDate);

                var selectedStartingTime =new Date(value.startTime * 1000 );
                var selectedEndingTime = new Date(value.endTime * 1000);

                //timing is not right, needs fixing
                startTime = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate(),selectedStartingTime.getUTCHours(), selectedStartingTime.getUTCMinutes());
                endTime = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate(),selectedEndingTime.getUTCHours(), selectedEndingTime.getUTCMinutes());                     
                // console.log(startTime);
                events.push({
                    title: 'Event -' + eventName,
                    startTime: startTime,
                    endTime: endTime,
                    allDay: false
                });

                $scope.calendar.eventSource= events;



        console.log(events);
        // console.log(value);




         //value is the object!!
        })
         return events;

        })

     }
```

This turned out to be not an issue with $scope.$broadcast in the documentation.